# How to create a TabControl Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, templates, tabcontrol

Look:

TabControl def:

```
<sdk:TabControl x:Name="tcWords">
                <sdk:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Letra}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Palabra}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Palabra}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            </sdk:TabControl>
```

Code:

```
public class Termino
    {
        public string Letra { get; set; }
        public string Palabra { get; set; }
        public string Significado { get; set; }
    }

  List<Termino> arrPalabras = new List<Termino>();
            arrPalabras.Add(new Termino { Letra = "A", Palabra = "Ave", Significado = "Cualquier cosa" });
            arrPalabras.Add(new Termino { Letra = "A", Palabra = "Avion", Significado = "Cualquier cosa avion" });
            //lstItems.ItemsSource = arrPalabras;
            tcWords.ItemsSource = arrPalabras;
```

It throws an exception!!!

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Paradigma.Silverlight.DiccionarioDatos.Termino'
>   to type
>   System.Windows.Controls.TabItem'.

Comment: when are you getting this exception? Is this a `Binding` exception in the output window or does the debugger pukes?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear but you can't bind your class `Termino` directly to the `ItemsSource` of the `TabControl` as it's not derived from `TabItem`.

You can try changing your declaration to:

```
public class Termino : TabItem
{
    ....
}
```

I *think* this should work.

The [documentation for `TabControl.ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) doesn't really help has it points to the `ItemsControl` page (which `TabControl` inherits from) so the examples are for that rather than `TabControl`.

Actually, thinking about it, you should be creating a list of `TabItems` to set to the `ItemsSource` of your `TabControl` and binding your class to the `TabItem`.

Comment: He is not binding his class but rather a list object `tcWords.ItemsSource = arrPalabras`

Comment: @Voodoo - but `TabControl` wants a list of `TabItems` not a list of `RandomClass`.

Comment: ok, but setting the `ItemsSource` on the TabControl will create those `TabItems`. (but maybe not??) - I have to say I confused myself on this one :)

Comment: @Voodoo - the error message states that it's trying to cast `Termino` to `TabItem` hence my answer, but your comment made me think some more.